# The connection between Image Segmentation with Neural Networks versus graph cut and mumford-shah type approaches

Tags: graph-theory, calculus-of-variations, image-processing

This question is meant to be a more technical question, so if I have phrased it as soliciting an opinion, any suggested language updates would be appreciated.

I am relatively new to image processing, but have been looking at both the Convolutional Neural Networks literature on image segmentation, as well as the literature on graph cut and Mumford-Shah type approaches to image segmentation. I understand that graph cuts is a particular interpretation of the image segmentation problem, and that the Mumford-Shah functional is one implementation of penalty by which to identify the cut edges. I have yet to find a Convolutional Neural Network paper that references the Mumford-Shah approaches, and *vice versa*.

Can anyone explain where Mumford-Shah approaches work better than CNNs, and where CNNs work better than Mumford-Shah. Are there particular domains in which one approach works better compared to the other--such as noisier backgrounds, etc. I realize that these questions are still open research areas.

Graph cut ideas of course extend to problems outside of image processing, however I was wondering if anyone has directly compared the efficiency or prediction error of graph cut image segmentation versus CNNs? CNNs face a number of challenges in generalizing to problems outside of their training sets, but I have not seen how well graph-cut methods compare on the same datasets.

It seems like the two literatures are proceeding in parallel, though of course there are obvious overlaps.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really compare graph cuts to CNNs. We use graph cuts to solve flow problems, and we use CNNs to learn patterns. We would only see this type of comparison if one was using each approach to solve a very specific problem (even more specific than image segmentation). While each method can be applied to segmentation, they have very different purposes and are applied to different problems.

Comment: Interesting. I mean one of the motivations for this question was a video on Coursera by Guillermo Sapiro entitled "Image Segmentation and Graph Cuts." https://www.coursera.org/learn/image-processing/lecture/jSq4p/8-graph-cuts-and-ms-office-duration-09-34. The application is to identify the objects in an image and then tag each pixel with the identifier for that object class. In other words labeling each pixel that belongs to a car in an image with a number like "5", where a dictionary indicates that 5 is a car.

Comment: I get what you are saying about the original application of graph cuts for flow problems. But it seems like this approach has been adapted for image segmentation. And image segmentation is also a popular topic for CNNs. So that is where I was coming from. I can cite more papers, if it would be helpful ?

Comment: I have used both graph cuts and CNNs for image segmentation, but I used them for very different problems. I would use something like a CNN for segmenting complex objects and graph cuts for a more simple segmentation (e.g. color, gradients, etc...). This is my opinion.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Is there a reason you still use graph cuts for simple operations, when a CNN could do the same thing? Just trying to understand the decision criteria. Is it the computational time for training the CNN, or do graph cuts do a better job for certain tasks, etc? I have not used graph cuts for this application before though I have seen others do it. Haha, the old difference in use I have seen is that people in the Math dept use graph cuts while CS and Stats use CNNs, but that is not a meaningful criteria.

Comment: CNNs require a lot of labeled data that may not be available

Answer (score 0):

GraphCuts performs much better than CNNs if the pixel labels are scarce. CNNs only perform better than GraphCuts if most pixels are labels. So you see, GraphCuts only needs weak supervision, but CNN needs full supervision, this is the biggest difference. Also, CNNs (and neural networks in general) have been facing the problem of lacking labelled data, and researchers investigated a lot into how to use GraphCuts to generate more labelled data to train CNNs, for example.

Comment: yes this makes sense. Graph cuts really just looks for energy minimization by cutting edge in the network, so it is not based upon labels. CNNs work on labels, so that is totally true--in segmentation especially. Thanks for the response, it made me think about this question again after a long time.